# Flutter location.altitude returns 0.0

Tags: flutter, dart, location

I know for certain that the my location has higher altitude than 0.0. However when I run this.

```
  LocationData point = await location.getLocation();
  elevation = point.altitude;
  print("Elevation: "+elevation.toString());
```

It outputs

> Elevation: 0.0

Comment: Does the machine you're running it on have an altitude sensor?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are having issues with finding altitude, it is most probably because of either a faulty sensor or the absence of such sensor.